# Why can't I put "x⁵" on a TextView but I can put "x⁴"?

Tags: android, textview

Why can't I put "x⁵" on a TextView but I can put "x⁴"?

```
<string name="secante_instru">Enter the following polynomial coefficients \n Ax⁵ + Bx⁴ + Cx³ + Dx² + Ex + F</string>
```

Comment: What exactly happens when you try it?

Comment: That's a... very descriptive title...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5 - exists, but it is not visible. It just takes up space. may be a bug with the font. Try to use another. [How to set custom font](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/customize-android-fonts/) Hope its help.

**UPDATE**

Try this:

```
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("x<sup>5</sup>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts

You could use unicode directly.

Example:

```
\u2075
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping double quote around it.